# Angular 4, custom pipe, for multiple columns

Tags: angular, sorting

I have created a custom pipe for sorting table column data and I want to make it dynamically called on icon click for each individual column in Angular 4? Is there any way to do that ? Any help on this part is appreciated.

Code goes as below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { Opportunity } from "../models/Opportunity";

@Pipe({
    name: "orderBy",
    pure: false
})

export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    /**
     * Method to sort data and return sorted data
     * 
     * @param records 
     * @param args 
     */
    transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
        return records.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a[args.property] < b[args.property]) {
                return -1 * args.order;
            }
            else if (a[args.property] > b[args.property]) {
                return 1 * args.order;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: (not solving issue, but) related and worth reading, I would do the sorting in the component instead :) https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 0):

you can call your pipe on click event :

```
import { SortPipe } from '@angular/common';
 ...
constructor(private sortPipe: SortPipe ) {}
...
sort() {
  this.dataArray= this.sortPipe.transform(this.dataArray);
 }
```

Comment: OK. without using component, Can I do that ?

Comment: yes: *ngFor="let item of (items | orderBy: 'property')"

Comment: That makes fixed sorting on table data. I am expecting dynamic sorting on each column selection